# Scipy Python wheel

Tags: python, numpy

I have got a problem with installing Scipy on my Python 2.7 , Windows in IPython.
When I enter "pip install scipy", I have one first error message:
"Failed building wheel for scipy" and then at the end

```
"
 Command "c:\python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools,tokenize;__file__='c:\\us    
 ers\\admini~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-e3yebj\\scipy\\setup.py';exec(com
 pile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __f
 ile__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-mwhxl
 d-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" faile
 d with error code 1 in c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-e3yebj\sci
 py
"
```

I do not know how to solve that problem, thanks if you have any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also met this problem and I then installed a Python distribution like Anaconda instead!

Answer (score 1):

You can download the wheel from this web site:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

You need to pick the right one. So, for

scipy‑0.19.0‑cp34‑cp34m‑win32.whl

cp34 means it will work with python 3.4

make sure you go with this one in your case:

scipy‑0.19.0‑**cp27**‑cp27m‑win32.whl and whatever your windows is (32 or 64).

once downloaded, go to the command line and put:

python -m pip install scipy‑0.19.0‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl (making sure it is sitting in the right directory).

That should solve the problem.